# How can I create a chart with stacked columns after drilldown?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a database with a lot of entries. It looks like the following example:

```
id | rating    | topic1 | topic2
1    positive    A        X
2    negative    A        Y
3    neutral     B        Z
```

Step 1:
Now I want to have a chart (highchart) showing stacked columns where each column is a topic (topic1) and the stacked parts are the amount of entries for each rating of this topic1. That chart is easy to create.

Step 2:
Additionally I would like to have a drilldown for each column. After clicking on a column I want to get again a stacked column chart where each column is the sub topic (topic2) of the clicked one and the stacked parts are the amount of entries for each rating of this topic2.

I've created an examplce. http://jsfiddle.net/9RLEB/2/

Step 1 is working fine but I can't get step 2 working. Can anyone please try to help me? Or give me a hint how I can achieve this result?

Thank you in advance.

Andi

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9RLEB/3/ ?

Comment: Not exactly, The result after drilling down should look like the following example http://jsfiddle.net/9RLEB/5/

So I need to set different positive/neutral/negative values for each topic2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, have you tried clicking the column title (the "A" and "B") to drilldown?

#### UPDATE

To make this actually working, you need to specify different drilldown for each data point:

```
series: [{
    name: 'negative',
    data: [{
      name: 'A',
      y: 13,
      drilldown: 'topic1Neg',
      color: '#e53642'
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      y: 42,
      drilldown: 'topic2Neg',
      color: '#e53642'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'neutral',
    data: [{
      name: 'A',
      y: 61,
      drilldown: 'topic1Neu',
      color: '#919191'
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      y: 23,
      drilldown: 'topic2Neu',
      color: '#919191'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'positive',
    data: [{
      name: 'A',
      y: 26,
      drilldown: 'topic1Pos',
      color: '#56cb46'
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      y: 11,
      drilldown: 'topic2Pos',
      color: '#56cb46'
    }]
  }
],
drilldown: {
  series: [{
    id: 'topic1Neg',
    data: [
      ['X', 4],
      ['Y', 2]
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'topic2Neg',
    data: [
      ['X', 5],
      ['Y', 3]
    ]
  },{
    id: 'topic1Neu',
    data: [
      ['X', 7],
      ['Y', 1]
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'topic2Neu',
    data: [
      ['X', 8],
      ['Y', 4]
    ]
  },{
    id: 'topic1Pos',
    data: [
      ['X', 2],
      ['Y', 3]
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'topic2Pos',
    data: [
      ['X', 9],
      ['Y', 5]
    ]
  }]
}
```

You just need to calculate the drilldown values yourself.

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/wyfqf/

[image: After clicking the title]

Comment: Actually I haven't. That is exactly how it should look in the end, but right now I only pass one value for each drilldown object. Thats why negative/neutral/positive have the same value. I want to pass three different values per subtopic. But I have no idea how I can do this (how the drilldown object should look like).

Comment: @AndreasDaoutis That's not hard. I just updated my answer. Please check if that's what you want.

Comment: Actually I think that's it. Let me try that in combination with my code. I'll come back later. Thank you already...